# Plotly merge multiple figures in one figure and overlay plots on each other

Tags: python, plotly

So I have multiple figures each representing a scatter plot which changes with a slider that updates the plot according to the slider's value. Now I need to merge all those figures into one figure and have one general slider which will show all the plots overlapped. Is there a way in plotly to combine multiple figures (***go.Figure() objects***) so I can get my desired output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69096931/how-do-i-combine-two-plots-into-one-figure-using-plotly does this help